# How to import Objective-C file to bridging header if it contains an import of Project-Swift.h

Tags: ios, swift, bridging-header

So, problem goes as is. I have a file that contains:

```
#import "Project-Swift.h"
```

And I want to add this file to my BridgingHeader.
So when I try to compile it, the error is as follows:

```
'Project/Project-Swift.h' file not found
#import "Project-Swift.h"
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header 'path/to/my/folder/Project/BridgingHeader.h'
```

I can not remove `#import "Project-Swift.h"` from this .h file as it's needed there. And I also want to use this Objc file in Swift. What are the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by including the `Project-Swift.h` header in the implementation `.m` file instead of the header file, and by using forward declarations in the header, e.g. `@class SomeClass`, `@protocol SomeProtocol`.

The solution is identical to the `Objective-C` solution when you have two classes depending one to each-other.

For example, given the following header file:

```
#import "Project-Swift.h"

@interface MyObjcClass: NSObject

@property SomeSwiftClass *aProperty;
@property id<SomeSwiftProtocol> delegate;
```

and the `.m` file like this

```
#import "MyObjClass.h"

@implementation MyObjcClass
...
```

, you need move the `#import "Project-Swift.h"` into the .m file, and update your header file like this:

```
@class SomeSwiftClass;
@protocol SomeSwiftProtocol;

@interface MyObjcClass: NSObject

@property SomeSwiftClass *aProperty;
@property id<SomeSwiftProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

and the `.m` file like this:

```
#import "Project-Swift.h"
#import "MyObjClass.h"

@implementation MyObjcClass
...
```

Note that you'll likely need to place the "Project-Swift.h" import before the one for your class header import if the objective-c class is declared to implement one of the Swift declared protocols.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, the only small issue is that it shows warning: Cannot find protocol definition for 'ARTPasscodeKeyboardControllerDelegate'

Comment: Have you added the forward declaration for the protocol, and included its header in the `.m` file? You might need to add that header before the one where you define your class, if the protocol is part of the class definition.

Comment: the matter is - this protocol is declared in swift file. I have added @protocol declaration but it still shows warning

Comment: Did you imported the headers in the order from my answer? i.e the -swift one first?

Comment: Yeah, swift one first. If I write this: @property (nonatomic) id<ARTPasscodeKeyboardControllerDelegate> delegate; it's fine, but the matter is this is a swift protocol and forward declaration shows warning as shown here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/70qfj95qnvaq7jj/Screenshot%202016-01-21%2021.44.46.png?dl=0

Comment: Is ARTPasscodeKeyboardControllerDelegate marked as available for Swift?

Comment: like this: @objc protocol ARTPasscodeKeyboardControllerDelegate